# wso2 esb service endpoint in request

Tags: wso2, esb, endpoint

> I am getting service endpoint as input SOAP request to WSO2 esb, based
>   on that need to send payload data to that endpoint and response to
>   client. Please advise how to send payload to that endpoint. I tried
>   Header mediator but no luck. Following is the SOAP XML request coming
>   to ESB which has service endpoint reference, under property element.
>
> `<soapenv:Envelope
>   xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
>   <soapenv:Body> <resources>   <resource>
>
>        <properties>
>         <property name="location" value="http://localhost:8280/services/echo.echoHttpSoap11Endpoint"/>
>       </properties>   </resource> </resources> </soapenv:Body> </soapenv:Envelope>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First retrieve the address value using the expression "//properties/property/@value". Then set the To address of the header mediator and send the message.

```
         <property name="address" expression="//properties/property/@value"/>
         <header name="To" expression="get-property('address')"/>
         <payloadFactory>
          <format>
           <p:echoInt xmlns:p="http://echo.services.core.carbon.wso2.org">
              <in xmlns="">$1</in>
           </p:echoInt>
         </format>
          <args>
           <arg value="1"/>
         </args>
        </payloadFactory>
     <send/>
```

Comment: I tried the same, but getting following error - org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The endpoint reference (EPR) for the Operation not found is /services/echo.echoHttpSoap11Endpoint and the WSA Action = null. If this EPR was previously reachable, please contact the server administrator.

Comment: Following is my sequence which I have attached in Out Sequence while defining proxy. '<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="inputEPSeq">
   <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="ServiceEP" expression="//resources/resource/properties/property/@value" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
   <header xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="To" expression="get-property('ServiceEP')"/>
   <send>
      <endpoint>
         <default/>
      </endpoint>
   </send>
   <out>
      <send/>
   </out>
</sequence>'

Comment: Following is my sequence attached in Out Seq while defining proxy. '<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="inputEPSeq"><property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="ServiceEP" expression="//resources/resource/properties/property/@value" scope="default" type="STRING"/><header xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="To" expression="get-property('ServiceEP')"/><payloadFactory><format><p:echoInt xmlns:p="http://echo.services.core.carbon.wso2.org">                  
<in xmlns="">1</in></p:echoInt></format></payloadFactory><send/><out><send/></out>/sequence>'

Comment: Latest error based on above sequence is - ERROR SequenceMediator Error while building message
org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxEOFException: Unexpected EOF in prolog
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,0]

Comment: I updated the answer with payloadfactory mediator to send the message. Here in your case remove the ; after <p:echoInt xmlns:p="echo.services.core.carbon.wso2.org"> and try.

Comment: I tried above with logging, it is failing with message - SequenceMediator Error while building message
org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxEOFException: Unexpected EOF in prolog

Comment: Following message is build up before send mediator 'To: http://localhost:8280/services/echo.echoHttpSoap11Endpoint WSAction: SOAPAction: MessageID: urn:uuid:add21951-4f97-464b-836d-be2e57056733 Direction: response ServiceEP = http://localhost:8280/services/echo.echoHttpSoap11Endpoint Envelope: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope
 xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soapenv:Body><p:echoInt xmlns:p="http://echo.services.core.carbon.wso2.org"><in>1</in></p:echoInt></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>'

Comment: Also, as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17194596/wso2-esb-overwrites-a-contenttype-property.....I have my axis2 changed to use NHTTP. Please advise if this can create any issue for solutioning of current problem we are trying to resolve ?

Comment: NHTTP in axis2.xml will create some problems. It will be better if you remove that with the previous one

Comment: Any idea what kind of issues it may give ?